# How to check the license of a LLM for specific use?

Tags: language-model, llm

How to check if a large language model has a license allowing to fine tune the model and then publish it publicly? How can I be sure that I can use and fine-tune a large language model without requiring permission issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLMs are usually uploaded by their creator company to Huggingface, and they specify the license. For instance, [Mixtral](https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-v0.1) has Apache License 2.0, while [Llama2](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b) has a custom license.

You should read the terms of the license of the model to understand if it fits your use case and constraints.